# What is the best approach to encapsulate business logic on rest application?

Tags: java, validation, rest

I'm working in a project that is using Resteasy, Spring, JPA and Hibernate.

all business logic is located on the controller (Rest Service) and i think to separate this business logic on another layer.

What is the best approach to separate and reuse business logics? In this business logic, there is a lot of validation rules too...

Thanks !

Comment: Be more specific about what you use for developing a Restful application. Jersey has clear documentation on this [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html). Spring MVC also is very well documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: @Cristian, sorry... I'm using Resteasy, Spring and JPA using Hibernate..

Comment: investigate the 'core java ee design patterns' if you want to make a good separation between business logic, validation and so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think about a Multitier Application, ok. If you are using it as a web-server, its advantageous to keep the input-validation in the view(javascript) and controller layer.

Its a good idea to have a clean interface design, respecting ACID (Atomicity+Consistency+Isolation+Durability), between the controller and the business layer.

This way, nothing can go wrong.

Comment: the validation logic inside controller how to reuse this validation through methods?

Comment: your validation logic inside the controllers are already in methods. What do you mean?

Comment: For example.. Inside a rest services, i have some methods that uses this validation...and actually i have this logic duplicated on these methods.. Is the best way create a method or a class that validates?

Comment: The business layer is **not** responsibility for input-validation work. See: If you validate you also must handle errors. Business layer have responsibility only for business-validation and business-error-handling.

Comment: Right.. but inside the controller, can i use some helper classes to validate fields ? Is this approach useful to reuse?

Comment: If the validation is in the responsibility of the controller, yes. In example: the Method `hasUserEnougthMoneyOnHisBankAccount(iban)` is business validation. The Method `isOver18(birthday)` is controller-validation (as long as it is an input of the user).